# Mono GUI Runtime How to hide the console window

Tags: xamarin, mono, xamarin-studio

I have a Mono Winforms project compiled with Xamarin Studio.  When I run from XS, it does not show a console windows.  However, after I bundle the package on the Mac( using mkbundle and pkgbuild) and then install it, a **bash shell is shown when I execute the program**.  When I exit the program,  the shell remains open with a final message "Process completed".  I then have to close the shell window.

I would like to be able to execute the application and not show the console window. It would also be acceptable if the shell window would close by itself when the application exits.

I tried and added this tag to my csproj but no good:
WinExe

I saw another post which stated to use a compiler switch to specify the target to be WinExe.  However, I do not see anywhere in XS to add custom compiler switches.  ( I think the switch was /target:WinExe).

Anyone have any workaround that these have used for this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had same problem and I solved it by adding /t:winexe to csc options list.

Answer (score 0):

**Project** options / **Build** / **General** / **Code Generation** / **Compile Target**

- Executable = `/target:exe`
- Library = `/target:library`
- Executable with GUI = `/target:winexe`
- Module = `/target:module`

[image]

Comment: Yes that is the option that I am using and still a bash shell windows comes up when running the **installed application**.  Note: when I run from within XS,  there is no shell and there is no issue.  As stated in my post- when I package the executable using mkbundle & pkgbuild and install it on my machine,  a bash shell comes up when I run the program.  So the question is still open.